# Importing existing products: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate Entry

Tags: magento2, database, import, url-rewrite, import-products

I have been importing existing products to a local environment through the admin dashboard. I realized that many of the products I imported didn't include their attributes, so I went back to make sure they were included by changing the 'Multiple value separator' to a pipe. Now though, when I import I get the following error:

```
General system exception happened
Additional data:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sauces-rubs/healthy-choices/gluten-free-default-category/healthy' for key 'url_rewrite.URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`store_id`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I have deleted all products and categories, I have wiped the url_rewrites table clean, and I have attempted to regenerate them using [this module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls). What am I missing? I am new to Magento, so please let me know if I need to include more information, but this is all that I am aware of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

product upload sheet for adding new product and updating certain attribute are different .

For updating the product attribute  you will just need product sku and attribute name that you want to update .

The url error appear when we have url already registered in the magento . If the url is not mentioned in the product sheet , the magento use product name to generate the product url and in that case if 2 products have same name , the error is thrown .

Nothing can be said without looking your product sheet .

1. you can change the product name slightly and try again
2. or you can explicitly add different url to the product csv sheet and resolve the error with the product
3. or you can go to magento admin panel under url rewrite section and generate different url for the problematic products

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here's the spreadsheet of products I wanted to add. I removed all the products and categories already, so shouldn't there not be any duplicates? I checked the spreadsheet as well, I couldn't find any duplicates there.